# Custom Function in Google Sheets Add-On

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, add-on, chrome-web-store

I'm trying to create a Custom Function for Google Sheets as an add-on.

Everything works fine in my spreadsheet, and I also can download it via Web chrome store
with the link Google provides me.

The only issue I have, is can't make the custom function work via the Google Sheets add-on store.

Don't know if I have to put further info in the `manifest.json` file, or do something else.

My app is registered, it has no connection to external services, and it only uses the usual javascript functions to split a string object.

Here is the code structure:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
      .addItem('Start', 'use')
      .addToUi();
}

/**
* Enables the add-on on for the current spreadsheet (simply by running) and
* shows a popup informing the user of the new functions that are available.
*/
function use() {
var title = "Example";
var message = "The Function GETID is now available in this spreadsheet";
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
ui.alert(title, message, ui.ButtonSet.OK);
}

function onInstall(e) {
    onOpen(e);
}

/**
* example
* @param {string} input the example URL.
* @return The example URL.
* @customfunction
*/
function GETID(URL) {
    return 'example '+URL;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Publishing a Google Add-on is a different processes to publishing a Chrome Web Store extension. Add-ons are also only in developer preview. This doesn't stop you publishing an add-on but it means that it first must be approved by Google. This [page contains a form for submitting your add-on for approval](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish) as well as other information about the publication process.